# Where clause using alias on one column of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I am trying to fetch some results using one column from a table, based on certain condition the results should be fetched.

Below is an query output: *This is reference data for my question below*.

```
select cdoctype, cfree7, cfree20
from TBISMT_DOCUMENTS
where cfree7 = '185768_TA'
```

[image]

*Another reference query and sample output*

```
select cdoctype, cfree7, cfree20
from TBISMT_DOCUMENTS
where cfree20 = '185768_TA'
```

[image]

**Objective is** : to check if any additional rows are present in db for each cdoctype = 850 and cfree7. In other words if there is any other cdoctype other than 850 for which, value in cfree7 matches to another row of cfree7 should be extracted.

I came up with below query and it working as expected but I am not sure how "t2.cfree20" value is showing as **185768_TA**  and it is working.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT t1.cwfid, t1.cdoctype, t1.cfree7, t2.cfree20, t1.cfree20 
 FROM TBISMT_DOCUMENTS t1,
      TBISMT_DOCUMENTS t2 
 WHERE t1.cfree7 = '185768_TA'
   and t1.cdoctype= '810'
   and t1.cfree7 = t2.cfree20
```

Below is sample output

[image]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: You want to check for a pârticular combinaison of cfree7 and cdoctype if another row has the same cfree7 but a different cdoctype is that right ?
Becaus ein your example you use 810 as cdoctype but you need to look for all cdoctype no ?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: `t1.cfree7 = '185768_TA'` and `t1.cfree7 = t2.cfree20`, so obviously t2.cfree20 is '185768_TA'. Why are you "not sure"?

Comment: @Carbon 4horse : Yes. I used 810 for an example , I was thinking to put an or condition to get the other cdoctype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to get all the row with the same cfree7 and cfree20 and a cdoctype not equal to 850

```
 SELECT 
         DISTINCT t1.cwfid,
         t1.cdoctype, 
         t1.cfree7,
         t2.cfree20, 
         t1.cfree20 
 FROM TBISMT_DOCUMENTS t1 
 Inner join TBISMT_DOCUMENTS t2  on t1.cfree7 = t2.cfree20
 WHERE t1.cdoctype != '850'
```

Answer (score 0):

> In other words if there is any other cdoctype other than 850 for which, value in cfree7 matches to another row of cfree7 should be extracted.

I interpret this as saying that you want any row where the value in `cfree7` matches the value in a row with `cdoctype = 850`.  If so:

```
select d.*
from TBISMT_DOCUMENTS d
where d.cdoctype <> 850 and
      exists (select 1
              from TBISMT_DOCUMENTS d2
              where d2.cfree7 = d.cfree7 and
                    d2.cdotype = 850
             );
```